# Related to concurrence of lines in triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

In triangle $ABC$, the straight lines $AD, BE, CF$ are drawn through a point $P$ to meet $BC, CA, AB$ at $D, E, F$ respectively. Prove that $PD/AD + PE/BE + PF/CF = 1$ and $AP/AD + BP/BE + CP/CF= 2.$

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: area.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows about a problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or using techniques above your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) As comments are easily overlooked, [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3613863/edit) to add details.

Comment: I saw this question in a book I am following for mathematical olympiad. I was not able to think how to start this question and n explain the solution at pre college level if possible. First lemme try it with ur hint.

Comment: No need to answer now I did it with your hint Thanks my dude. How can I delete this question now?

Comment: @AryanRaina: You should post your solution in an answer. That way we can upvote your success! (You can also eventually accept your own answer.) Also, someone may be working on the problem, and it's no fun returning to find a question deleted.

Comment: I guess I posted it but I don't know how to start a new line in SE answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a parallel to $BC$ is drawn from $P$, we can state that it cuts the perpendicular to $BC$ in ratio of $PD/AD$. This implies
$$\frac{\frac12BC\cdot PD}{\frac12 BC\cdot AD}=\frac{PD}{AD}=\frac{[BPC]}{[ABC]} \tag{1}$$

Similarly, 
$$
\frac{PF}{CF} =\frac{[APB]}{[ABC]} \qquad\qquad
\frac{PE}{BE} =\frac{[APC]}{[ABC]}  \tag{2}
$$

Therefore, 
$$\frac{PD}{AD}+\frac{PE}{BE}+\frac{PF}{CF} = 
\frac{[BPC]+[APC]+[APB]}{[ABC]} =\frac{[ABC]}{[ABC]}= 1 \tag{3}$$

Also,
$$\frac{AP}{AD}=\frac{[ABP]}{[ABD]}=\frac{[APC]}{[APD]}=
\frac{[ABP]+[APC]}{[ABD]+[APD]}=\frac{[ABP]+[APC]}{[ABC]}\tag{4}$$ 
(because perpendicular from $AD$ and $AP$ to $B$ will be same and that to $C$ will be same)

Similarly, 
$$\frac{BP}{BE}=\frac{[BPC]+[BPA]}{[ABC]} \qquad\qquad
\frac{CP}{CF}=\frac{[CPA]+[CPB]}{[ABC]} \tag{5}
$$

Therefore, 
$$\begin{align}
\frac{AP}{AD}+\frac{BP}{BE}+\frac{CP}{CF} &=\frac{[APB]+[APC]+[BPC]+[BPA]+[CPA]+[CPB]}{[ABC]} \\[4pt]
&=\frac{2\cdot[ABC]}{[ABC]} \\[4pt]
&=2 \tag{6}
\end{align}$$